# Calculate cohort conversion rate at time T in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

| Cohort | Signup date | Converted date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Jan 1 | Jan 2 |
| A | Feb 1 | Feb 3 |
| A | Mar 1 | Mar 4 |
| A | Apr 1 | Apr 5 |
| B | May 1 | May 3 |
| B | Jun 1 | Jun 5 |
| B | July 1 | July 7 |

And I want to get the cohort specific conversion rate a time, T, after sign up. So the table should look something like this:

| Cohort | Days after signup | Conversion rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0.00 |
| A | 1 | 0.25 |
| A | 2 | 0.50 |
| A | 3 | 0.75 |
| A | 4 | 1.00 |
| A | 5 | 1.00 |
| A | 6 | 1.00 |
| A | 7 | 1.00 |
| B | 0 | 0.00 |
| B | 1 | 0.00 |
| B | 2 | 0.33 |
| B | 3 | 0.33 |
| B | 4 | 0.66 |
| B | 5 | 0.66 |
| B | 6 | 1.00 |
| B | 7 | 1.00 |

Comment: `Signup date` , `Signup date`  ?

Comment: Oops! Should be `Signup date` and `Converted date`

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a series of numbers and cross join all Gohorts to get the items in question.
Now you can use window functions. For example

Sample data

```
select * into tbl
from (
   values
     ('A', 1),
     ('A', 2),
     ('A', 3),
     ('A', 4),
     ('B', 2),
     ('B', 4),
     ('B', 6)
)t(Cohort, ndays);
```

The query

```
select s.s, c.Cohort
   , 1.0 * count(t.ndays) over(partition by c.Cohort order by s.s) / count(t.ndays) over(partition by c.Cohort) convertion 
from generate_series(0,7) s
cross join (select distinct Cohort from tbl) c
left join tbl t on t.Cohort = c.Cohort and t.ndays = s.s 
order by c.Cohort, s.s;
```